# Full-trusted proxy for SP2013 sandbox solution

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution

In my sandboxed solution I have the following code that activates a proxy:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            var type = typeof (ManagedLicenses.LicenseValidatorProxy);
            var proxyOperationType = new SPProxyOperationType(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
            var userCodeService = SPUserCodeService.Local;
            userCodeService.ProxyOperationTypes.Add(proxyOperationType);
            userCodeService.Update();
        }
```

Everything works fine on SharePoint 2010 - however I can't get it to work on SharePoint 2013 as I get the following exception thrown:

> Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute
>   method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has
>   occurred. - userCodeWrapperType =
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper",
>   userAssemblyGroupId =
>   "1E58ADFF1BC14371BE7F7489551FBC5C-jfb9KwaIeEukOpyOxra2T8r/NE+fdQzldzg4bIF7Pfc=",
>   siteCollectionId = "c4c2d6ab-8e79-491e-9d16-051a98696a4d" - Inner
>   Exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: This
>   code is calling a privileged proxy operation that is not available on
>   this farm.  Please contact your farm administrator.

I wonder if anybody else here had similar problems or knows a solution.

Comment: Is this even supported in SharePoint 2013? "Sandbox Solutions changed their relationship status to 'it's complicated'". (That's the most accurate way I can describe the obsolete/deprecated status of SandBox solutions in 2013, nobody knows the truth yet).

Comment: I would love to get an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot activate a Proxy in a Sandboxed solution, that would violate the security mechanism.

Comment: Hi Wictor, thanks for reading my question. I am not sure you understood it correctly though - my example is straight from msdn and I am confident the proxy serves exactly the purpose I am trying to use it for.